# Grouping together several read dates into clusters, Nth reading of that year

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
+------------+------+
| 2011-03-04 |    6 |
| 2011-03-01 |    1 |
| 2011-02-28 |    4 |
| 2011-02-24 |    1 |
| 2011-02-23 |    1 |
| 2011-02-22 |    2 |
| 2011-02-17 |    1 |
| 2011-02-16 |   22 |
| 2011-02-12 | 2033 |
| 2011-02-10 |    1 |
| 2011-02-07 |    1 |
| 2011-01-04 |    1 |
| 2011-01-03 |    5 |
| 2010-12-26 |    6 |
| 2010-12-16 |    1 |
| 2010-12-15 |  158 |
| 2010-12-14 | 1703 |
| 2010-12-13 |  199 |
| 2010-11-08 |    1 |
| 2010-10-28 |    3 |
| 2010-10-27 |    6 |
| 2010-10-25 |    1 |
| 2010-10-21 |  660 |
| 2010-10-20 |  558 |
| 2010-10-19 |  245 |
| 2010-10-18 |  579 |
| 2010-10-15 |   14 |
| 2010-10-14 |    1 |
| 2010-10-04 |    1 |
| 2010-09-08 |    1 |
| 2010-09-01 |    1 |
| 2010-08-31 |    1 |
| 2010-08-30 |    6 |
| 2010-08-26 |    1 |
| 2010-08-24 |    4 |
| 2010-08-23 |    2 |
| 2010-08-19 |    3 |
| 2010-08-18 |  144 |
| 2010-08-17 |  920 |
| 2010-08-16 |  982 |
| 2010-08-03 |    1 |
| 2010-08-02 |    1 |
| 2010-07-12 |    1 |
| 2010-06-30 |    8 |
| 2010-06-29 |    1 |
| 2010-06-28 |    1 |
| 2010-06-23 |    1 |
| 2010-06-22 |    1 |
| 2010-06-17 |    7 |
| 2010-06-16 |  703 |
| 2010-06-15 |  937 |
| 2010-06-14 |  397 |
| 2010-06-10 |    2 |
| 2010-06-09 |    1 |
| 2010-06-01 |    5 |
| 2010-05-26 |    1 |
| 2010-05-05 |    1 |
| 2010-04-27 |    2 |
| 2010-04-26 |    4 |
| 2010-04-24 |    6 |
| 2010-04-22 |    2 |
| 2010-04-21 |  351 |
| 2010-04-20 |  839 |
| 2010-04-19 |  850 |
| 2010-04-18 |    2 |
| 2010-04-15 |    2 |
| 2010-04-07 |    1 |
| 2010-04-01 |    2 |
| 2010-03-30 |    1 |
| 2010-03-22 |    1 |
| 2010-03-10 |    1 |
| 2010-03-08 |    1 |
| 2010-03-04 |    1 |
| 2010-03-01 |    3 |
| 2010-02-27 |    6 |
| 2010-02-25 |    2 |
| 2010-02-23 |    4 |
| 2010-02-22 |    1 |
| 2010-02-18 |  188 |
| 2010-02-17 | 1210 |
| 2010-02-16 |  646 |
| 2010-01-27 |    1 |
| 2010-01-21 |    1 |
| 2010-01-07 |    1 |
| 2010-01-06 |    2 |
| 2010-01-04 |   12 |
+------------+------+
```

I have this data set for the last years. I would like to group similar reading dates into one. Like take range 2011-02-07 and 2011-03-04 and combine them together as reading no: 1 of that year.

Or combine 2010-10-04 and 2010-10-28 as reading no: 5th of that year.

Groupings are similar based on count of readings, based on the 2nd column. There are spikes that needs to be grouped together. It will be 6 periods in each year and at least 40 days of difference between them.

How can I do that in MySQL?

Comment: Do you mean you want to automatically match the spike periods or will you define these manually?

Comment: I want to match automatically spikes into 6 groups each year.

Comment: I saw some date examples in your post but I didn't understand what defined those dates as the cut-off points. Can you elaborate?

Comment: For example dates around `2011-02-12` with 2033 are grouped together with reading number 1 of the year. Dates around `2010-04-19` with 850 are grouped together as reading number 2 of that year. Dates between the spikes must be grouped to the closest spikes.

Comment: All right, the cut-off dates seem now well defined. Now what about the spikes? How are they supposed to be detected? Or is that actually the question?

Comment: I agree with James. You should think about a different approach, since your definitions are unclear. I would think that you might want to start with selecting the Top 6 of your second column and then expanding your date ranges from there. However, your question is confusing to me. How are the readings between `2011-02-07` and `2011-03-04` similar? They contain a very large spike that is quite dissimilar from the other readings. But it seems from your comments that you mean that these dates are grouped around the spike, so it is the spike, or dissimilarity, that is important in choosing the per

Comment: Spikes are the days when near them a lot of readings were made. Like `2010-02-17`, `2010-04-19`

Comment: @Pentium10: Yes, I *can* distinguish the spikes in your sample data, but only with my eyes. :) The question was, how can they be determined programmatically? I was expecting something like a threshold value to check for, or maybe a formula – is there anything?

Comment: @Pentium10: Or do you mean that they should be found by the accumulations of multiple readings in a row around them? That is, they are somewhere in the middle of the sequences of multiple readings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your sample data and threw it into a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `usage_bill` (
  `readdate` date default NULL,
  `reading` int(11) default NULL
);
```

I've got as far as being able to detect the peaks in a generic way like this:

```
SET @seq1 := 0;
SET @seq2 := 0;

SET @lastdiff := 0;

SELECT readdate, reading FROM  (
    SELECT ref2.readdate, ref1.reading, ref2.reading - ref1.reading AS diff,
        (@lastdiff>0) && (ref2.reading - ref1.reading)<0 AS peak,
            @lastdiff := ref2.reading - ref1.reading AS lastdiff FROM
        (SELECT @seq1 := @seq1 + 1 AS rowNum, readdate, reading FROM usage_bill ORDER BY readdate) AS ref1,
        (SELECT @seq2 := @seq2 + 1 AS rowNum, readdate, reading FROM usage_bill ORDER BY readdate) AS ref2
        WHERE ref1.rowNum+1 = ref2.rowNum ) AS peaks
WHERE peak=1;
```

In theory it should be possible to just add `ORDER BY reading DESC LIMIT 6` to get the biggest peaks but in practice it's not as not all of the peaks are clean curves (e.g. October 2010).

Not sure if this helps you at all...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working by using user-variables, but there is a slight problem with it.

```
SET @stepdate:=DATE('1970-01-01'); 

SET @reading:=0; 

SET @prevdate:=DATE('1970-01-01'); 

SELECT readdate, 
       IF(( To_days(`readdate`) - To_days(@stepdate) ) > 40 
           OR (SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM   usage_bill 
               WHERE  readdate BETWEEN d.readdate AND DATE_ADD(d.readdate, 
                                                      INTERVAL 25 DAY 
                                                      ) > 
                      100), @reading := @reading + 1, @reading) AS rownum, 
       IF(( To_days(`readdate`) - To_days(@stepdate) ) > 40 
           OR (SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM   usage_bill 
               WHERE  readdate BETWEEN d.readdate AND DATE_ADD(d.readdate, 
                                                      INTERVAL 25 DAY 
                                                      ) > 
                      100), @stepdate := readdate, @stepdate)   AS dd, 
       IF(YEAR(@stepdate)<>YEAR(@prevdate), @reading := 1 XOR 
                                            @prevdate := @stepdate, 
       @reading), 
       @reading                                                 AS nthgroup 
FROM   (SELECT `readdate`, 
               COUNT(*) c 
        FROM   `usage_bill` 
        GROUP  BY `readdate` 
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 20 
        ORDER  BY `usage_bill`.`readdate` ASC) d
```

The problem is that when I remove `HAVING COUNT(*) > 20` I get read dates that are miss placed between read dates and compose a new group.